# nginx doens't run php files

Tags: php, apache, nginx

when I tried access to http://carviz.pt/ it is download a file instead that run the website
this is a result of nginx -V:

```
    configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-
path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-
temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-
path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-
path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --
with-pcre-jit --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-
http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-
http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-
http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-
md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/nginx-
XCySkU/nginx-1.2.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-XCySkU/nginx-
1.2.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-XCySkU/nginx-
1.2.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-XCySkU/nginx-
1.2.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
```

first I have apache installed but then I decided change so I remove all packages from apache and reinstalled nginx but now php doesn't work... doI need to recompile or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no nginx expert(did not start using it yet) but I know that you need to configure nginx and link it to fast cgi to be able to compile the php code 
see link: http://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-php-behind-nginx-with-fastcgi/